# Key Points/Challenges while working with Apache Tika and Solr

Tags: solr, apache-tika

Recently I got involved in a task, and part of it require to use Apache Solr ( for Document Search) ,and Apache Tika ( to Extract the meta-text or plain text from documents)

I have n't integrated Solr and tika yet ,But I have worked with both of them individually I might have set of questions related to Apache Solr and Apache Tika , It might be at beginners level or average.

Following types of practical I did with Solr e.g. created a dummy database, wrote a program, configured - schema.xml things, ran Solr sever, and program which fetches documents from database and store in Solr Document Index , Made a Simple client to fetch data from Solr via JSON Interface, Made a Program which keeps MySQL Database to sync with Apache’s Solr document Index.

Following types of practical I did with tika e.g. compiled and Installed Tika, understood its document parsing capablities.
  ..
My Sample Task statement:
Part of my  project require to store around 100,000 of documents (Data of these 100,000 (Doc,PDF,Txt) docs are fetched by Apache tika and pushed to MySql’s Database and later that pushed to apache Solr’s Document Database)for *Full Text Search* and search them those via a client interface (Browser)

- In simple programmatical level this task will get done,

I would like to understand the challenges related to managing the index or something else in Solr e.g.

** In advanced level does it require optimizing the Solr’s Open Source Code?

** While Solr works in proper way, does it provide any specific challenges?

** What Key things need to consider initially so that, Solr should work in a proper way.

** Do you think any extra tool to developed to monitor Solr’s working ?

Hope you got the idea related to questions I have ?

** Also I would like to know If you have any experience of using apache Tika with apache Solr, and any challenges or key things to consider ?

Would you like to recommend and specific sources Or If you have any document or anything which you feel to be helpful.

Comment: Why are you not doing the Tika conversion inline in SOLR? I'd have thought that would be simpler than doing the Tika step first, saving some intermediate text in the database, then indexing that

Comment: May you please explain a little more about your approach ?

Comment: You'd use *ExtractingRequestHandler* to call Tika from within SOLR, and you'd then post the original binary doc to SOLR for indexing. If you google for "Tika SOLR" or "ExtractingRequestHandler" you should find loads of info on it